# How can I form polygons from lines

Tags: algorithm, geometry, polygon

I have a bunch of 2-dimensional lines, whose start and end points are known. The lines might occasionally cross each other, or one line might end in the middle of another line. I need to form polygons from this mesh of lines. If necessary, I can ensure that the left side of all lines are inside their polygons.

Comment: and here i was thinking that lines have only one dimension... something new every day :)

Comment: @hop: I think he meant he has a set of lines on a 2-dimensional plane as opposed to residing in 3-dimensional space.

Comment: Perhaps the answer to my question will also help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13847933/locating-bounding-2d-entities/13850355#13850355

Answer (score 2):

What you're describing is what we called "parcelization" or "spaghetti cutting", and then "polygonization" when I worked for GeoVision.  Basically you want to cut the lines where-ever they intersect other lines and themselves, and then you want to assemble them into polygons by traversing line/node/line until you find a closed polygon.